# kernel Disabling IRQ #49

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, interrupts

I am using the RPi_GPIO library in a python shell to read a raw wireless signal using the wait_for_edge() function in a loop like so:

```
while True:
   GPIO.wait_for_edge(26, GPIO.RISING)
   print 'R'
   GPIO.wait_for_edge(26, GPIO.FALLING)
   print 'F'
```

Meanwhile in another python shell on the same machine, I am doing a cheesy PWM by switching GPIO 21 HIGH/LOW and calling sleep() in between like this:

```
while True
   GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
   sleep(20)
   GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
   sleep(20)
```

My goal was just to verify that I had everything wired up and could send/receive signal. Maybe 30 seconds in, I got a message in both shells that said:

> Message from syslogd@raspb2 at May 19 21:35:26 ...
>   kernel:[ 9675.681566] Disabling IRQ #49

This is what I see in /proc/interrupts:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
 16:          0          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  16  bcm2708_fb dma
 24:        262          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  24  DMA IRQ
 25:       2887          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  25  DMA IRQ
 32:    6527881          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  32  dwc_otg, dwc_otg_pcd, dwc_otg_hcd:usb1
 49:     200000          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  49  3f200000.gpio:bank0
 50:          0          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  50  3f200000.gpio:bank1
 65:         44          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  65  ARM Mailbox IRQ
 66:          2          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  66  VCHIQ doorbell
 75:          1          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  75
 79:          0          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  79  3f804000.i2c
 80:          0          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  80  3f204000.spi
 83:         17          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  83  uart-pl011
 84:      19653          0          0          0   ARMCTRL  84  mmc0
 99:      81407      60633      23147      50785   ARMCTRL  99  arch_timer
474:      15968          0          0          0  pinctrl-bcm2835  26  gpiolib
FIQ:              usb_fiq
IPI0:          0          0          0          0  CPU wakeup interrupts
IPI1:          0          0          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI2:      59304      52831      74083      54061  Rescheduling interrupts
IPI3:          7          6          9         12  Function call interrupts
IPI4:          3          4          1          2  Single function call interrupts
IPI5:          0          0          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
IPI6:          0          0          0          0  IRQ work interrupts
IPI7:          0          0          0          0  completion interrupts
Err:          0
```

IRQ #49 appears to be gpio:bank0 (I never knew there were different banks for the GPIO). I am guessing that I have overrun a buffer or something while trying to read and write so rapidly. Maybe both of these pins are on the same bank and I could us a different pin for one of the loops that is on the other bank. Unfortunately a quick google search did not turn up a reference for which pins are on which bank. I don't think this is a show-stopper but now my interest is peaked.  Anyone have this problem before or have some insight into what it is? What is the maximum speed at which I can/should read/write on GPIO pins?

Comment: At least a link to the GPIO banks assignment info. http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-compute-module/compute-module-io-pins